# Simple while loop wont break

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm completely new to python and coding in general, it's probably some ridiculously obvious error but I can't figure out why this while loop won't break.

I'm trying to find the value of t when y is equal to 0. When changing t manually, y is less than 0 when t is just under 2.5.

Unfortunately I don't have anyone else I can ask for right now. Thanks!

```
t = 0
y0 = 1.8
v0 = 15.0
theta0 = 0.785398163
vy0 = v0*sin(theta0)
ay0 = -9.81

y = y0 + vy0*t + 0.5*ay0*t**2

while y > 0:
    print(t)
    t += 0.25
    if y < 0:
        break
    print(t)
```

Comment: This loop seems completely wrong. You are not modifying y anywhere in the loop. And generally you don't really need the y < 0 check.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include your equation in the loop so that the value of y changes each time you increase t. Like this:

```
while y > 0:
    y = y0 + vy0*t + 0.5*ay0*t**2
    print(t)
    t += 0.25
    if y < 0:
        break print(t)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could restructure your loop as follows:

```
t = 0
y0 = 1.8
v0 = 15.0
theta0 = 0.785398163
vy0 = v0*sin(theta0)
ay0 = -9.81
y = 1       # dummy start value

while y >= 0:
    y = y0 + vy0*t + 0.5*ay0*t**2
    print("t={}, y={}".format(t,y))
    t += 0.25
```

This would then also display all of the values as it loops, so you can see it working:

```
t=0, y=1.8
t=0.25, y=4.145087928395659
t=0.5, y=5.8770508567913184
t=0.75, y=6.9958887851869775
t=1.0, y=7.501601713582638
t=1.25, y=7.394189641978297
t=1.5, y=6.673652570373955
t=1.75, y=5.339990498769618
t=2.0, y=3.3932034271652753
t=2.25, y=0.8332913555609345
t=2.5, y=-2.3397457160434065
```

By adding a dummy start value, it ensures that the loop will be entered, and avoids the need to also add a `break` statement within the loop.

From these results you can see there is a solution somewhere between `2.25` and `2.5`. You could then change your start value to say `t = 2.25` and change the increment to `t += 0.01` and you would see a slightly more accurate estimation.

Comment: Thanks this was actually exactly what I needed! Just 1 question, how would I find the exact t value when y = 0?

Comment: This way of solving things is usually just an estimation. I have updated the explanation to show you how you could improve the result. Keep going until you find a solution. Obviously it can be solved with Python using math. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

`while y > 0`

at this line loop will start when `y > 0`, but then you didn't change the value of `y` during `while` loop then how `if y < 0` this statement will execute.

And your `y = 1.8` after calculating `y = y0 + vy0*t + 0.5*ay0*t**2` so it is an infinite loop as `y > 0` is all time true.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from other answers, you need to move your equation to inside the while loop.

In programming the assignment operator (this thing: `=`) does not create relationships between variables. It (usually) simply takes what is on the right and puts it in what is on the left.

Consider this code:

```
y = 0
x = y+1
y = 33
print x
```

It will print out 1.

`y+1` gets evaluated to `0+1` then `1`.

Then `x` gets set to the integer value of 1.

Changing y will not do anything because x was set to the specific value of that expression at that specific time, not to a reference.

You might have noticed the "usually" in my definition of the assignment operators, that's because references do exist in programming and specifically in python. For example this happens when you set a variable equal to an uninstantiated class, but at this point understanding that is not necessary.